# Excel VBA Solver (Internal Reference)

Tags: vba, excel

I am not sure if I am overambitious here, but I was trying to use Solver by referring to all the data that I have coded in my VBA previously (i.e. nothing on the worksheet at all).

```
   SolverOk SetCell:="psharpe", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="activew", Engine _
    :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="activew,marketw", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverOk SetCell:="psharpe", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="activew", Engine _
    :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="psharpe", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="activew", Engine _
    :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve
```

My code before this is correct.. But I am not sure if this is possible (error at the moment :()

Thank you so much in advance!

Update: Apologises, the 'psharpe', 'activew', 'marketw' are all values solved within the VBA (i.e. it is not on the Excel Spreadsheet). So would that not be possible?

Comment: is "psharpe" a Named Range ?  so is "activew" ?

Comment: Please add your declarations, so we can see what is what.

Comment: I don't think that Solver could work with VBA variables, but only with ranges so if "psharpe" it is not a range, probably this is the reason you get the error.